# increase pen width with trackbar value

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

As the it's said in the title, i am trying to increase pen width size by using a trackbar.
This is what i have written so far:

```
public partial class Form26_10 : Form
    {
        float scrollValue = 0F;

        Pen CustomPen = new Pen(Color.Black, scrollValue);//ERROR<-

        public Form26_10()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

     private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scrollValue = trackBar1.Value;
    }
```

}

essentially i should be able to declare a value in memory, then have it in the pen width parameter and so when the trackbar value change's the pen width changes. Though i am getting this error:

```
a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property of 'Form.scrollValue'
```

Comment: It is just the wrong approach.  Only ever create a Pen object when you need it.  With the using statement.  At which point you can use trackBar1.Value in its constructor and it will have an appropriate value.  All that trackBar1_Scroll should do is call Invalidate() so whatever code that uses the pen runs again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form26_10 : Form
{
    private Pen CustomPen;

    public Form26_10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CustomPen = new Pen(Color.Black, scrollValue);
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomPen.Width = trackBar1.Value;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't initialize class fields at declaration if you've got a changing value. Also, float has a default value of 0.0F so you don't need to initialize it. I removed it in this example because I assumed you wouldn't need it. If you still plan on using it, you can just add it at the top.

```
float scrollValue;
```